# Cant call getLayoutInflater when using SwipeStack

Tags: android, android-context

I'm still new at learning android and trying to implement a swipestack using the SwipeStack library. When using the code as it appears on GitHub, getLayoutInflater as well as getActivity does not resolve. Reading on the web, it seems I need to declare a context, but I am unsure how to do this. Any help will be great! My code below:

```
    import ...


public class RateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}

public class SwipeStackAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<String> mData;

public SwipeStackAdapter(List<String> data) {
    this.mData = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
    TextView textViewCard = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard);
    textViewCard.setText(mData.get(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Pass the Context within the Constractor: 
public SwipeStackAdapter(List<String> data, Context context) {
    this.mData = data;
    this.context = context;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling SwipeStackAdapter from an activity, define it so it receives a Context object and call it passing "this" in the corresponding field. Otherwise you can pass getActivity() or getApplicationContext() to this field. Then in the adapter create a global variable called context and asign the context you are receiving to this variable.

When you need to call getLayoutInflater just use
`context.getLayoutInflater();`